# Running batch file from VBScript: cannot find the specified file (error 80070002)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I want to execute a batch file using VBScript. When I use this code, cmd.exe does run but only for a short period of time and the batch file does not get executed.

test.vbs:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Exec "test.bat"
```

But when I run this script, it says that it can not find the specified file (error 80070002). The batch file works fine in cmd.exe. I've tried putting echo hello in the script of the batch file, but nothing works! I have put the .vbs and .bat file in the same directories. The .bat file only outputs some strings, uses the timeout command and pings an IP address

What can I do to execute the batch file?

Comment: Do you have the correct _current working directory_?

Comment: The `Exec` method runs the given command asynchronously in the background, which is probably not what you want here. Use the `Run` method instead.

Comment: @Vedant Jain - Did you find a solution?  What was the problem?  Let us know if any of our suggestions helped: 1) Use .run, 2) Test and verify the .bat separately from the .vbs,3) Ensure the .vbs is invoked so that it is running in the correct directory, with the correct permissions.  Please update your post with what you found.

Answer (score -1):

1. I think what you've got *should* work fine.
2. Important questions:

   a. What exactly is in your .bat file?  Perhaps it's doing something that doesn't work from ShellExec/Shell.run?

   b. How exactly are you starting your VBS script?  Perhaps it can't even find the test.bat file?  For example, maybe the .vbs is executing in the wrong working  directory?

   c. Do you call another .bat file from inside your .bat file?  If so, always use "Call".  EXAMPLE: "call mysecondbat.bat".

   d. Are there any spaces in the .bat file's path, or filename?  If so, you'll need "triple spaces".  EXAMPLE: shell.run """F:\My Server\My Path\Test.bat"""
3. SUGGESTION:

   a. Create a "test.bat" that does something simple (like "echo Hello")

   b. Run the .bat file from a command prompt - verify it's OK.

   c. Then run the .vbs from the same command prompt, and verify the .bat file still runs OK.
4. EXAMPLE:

   testvbs.vbs:

   ```
   dim shell
   set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
   shell.run "test.bat"
   set shell=nothing
   ```

   testbat.bat:

   ```
   echo I'm in testbat.bat!
   @PING localhost -n 6 >NUL
   ```

   From a command prompt, type "testvbs.vbs".  A window should appear, saying "I'm in testbat.bat!", then disappear after 5 seconds or so.

   Compare with your .vbs file.  Update your post with what you've found.

Comment: Thanks For the suggestion! But when I run this script, it says that it can not find the specified file (error 80070002). The batch file works fine in cmd.exe. I've tried putting echo hello in the script of the batch file, but nothing works! I have put the .vbs and .bat file in the same directories. The .bat file only outputs some strings, uses the timeout command and pings an IP address.

Comment: I've re-written the response.  Please read it, try my suggestions, and update your post.  I also took the liberty of updating the title, and adding the error message, to your original post.